# Auto-forward to another instance?

Tags: azureservicebus

Is it possible to configure Service Bus (on premise) to forward messages to another on premise Service Bus instance?

The [Azure Auto-forwarding feature documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-auto-forwarding/) seems to focus on forwarding messages to the same instance of Service Bus, within the same namespace.

It's also unclear whether Auto-forwarding is an Azure-only feature, or whether it applies equally on premise.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-Forwarding feature is to forward within the same **namespace**. So you can't forward to another namespace or instance. That would be a custom application responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

> The Service Bus autoforwarding feature enables you to chain a queue or subscription to another queue or topic that is part of the same namespace. When autoforwarding is enabled, Service Bus automatically removes messages that are placed in the first queue or subscription (source) and puts them in the second queue or topic (destination). It is still possible to send a message to the destination entity directly. Also, it is not possible to chain a subqueue, such as a deadletter queue, to another queue or topic.

Refer [Chaining Service Bus entities with autoforwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding)

So, by using the autoforward property the messages can be chained only within the entities of the same namespace.

Inorder to forward your messages to your on premise entities you should write a custom code to send the messages.